# Converse to Lefschetz fixed point theorem (counterexample)

Tags: examples-counterexamples, fixed-point-theorems

The celebrated [Lefschetz fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem), in its simplest form, says (following Wikipedia) that if $f\colon X \to X$ is a continuous map of a compact triangulable space $X$ to itself, then $f$ has at least one fixed point, provided that the value $\Lambda_f$ given by:
$$
     \Lambda_f:=\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k\mathrm{Tr}(f_*|H_k(X,\mathbb{Q})), 
$$
is non-zero.

What is an example when the converse fails to be true? I.e., what is an example of a space $X$ and a function $f$ such that $\Lambda_f$ is $0$, but nevertheless any function homotopic to $f$ needs to have a fixed point?

Comment: Do you want to have $X$ connected?

Comment: @PeterFranek: Yes :)

Comment: Consider the wedge of two circles, and $f$ the map that kills off one circle and flips the other one (i.e., a degree $-1$ map on the second). This has $\Lambda_f=0$; I'm convinced but haven't checked the details that any map homotopic to it has a fixed point.

Comment: I believe that Mike's construction might work. On the other hand, I found some online papers that the converse holds if $X$ is a compact connected simply connected manifold.

Comment: @PeterFranek What do you specifically mean by the converse? That if $\Lambda_f=0$, then some map homotopic to $f$ has no fixed points?

Comment: @MikeMiller: Yes, at least it is written in the abstract of Brown: On a homotopy converse to the Lefschetz fixed point theorem.

Comment: In Mike's example  $\mathrm{Tr}(f_*|H_0(X,\mathbb{Q})) = 1, \mathrm{Tr}(f_*|H_1(X,\mathbb{Q})) = -1$. Then $\Lambda_f = 2$. The mistake is probably that you have to take alternating sum of traces, not just the sum.